# Is there an equivalent of PHP's $$ in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

In PHP you can dynamically interpret a variable name.  So if you do

```
<?php
$bar = "a string";
$foo = "bar";
echo $$foo;
```

It will print "a string".  Can you do this in Ruby?

Comment: FWIW, that syntax is ugly and ambiguous, better to use `${$foo}`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `eval` for this.

Example: eval(variable name as string)

```
a = 4
eval('a') # it is 4.
```

Comment: Please don't. There is absolutely no reason to use `eval` here. `Binding#local_variable_get` has existed for more than three years and the last version of Ruby that didn't have it isn't even maintained anymore.